# Using linux command deleting files in different folders simultaneously

Tags: linux

I would like to know how to delete files simultaneously in different folders?

I got lots of files in these folders and it takes too long to delete all of that.

There's one limitation in my case,I have too many files to use command like `rm -rf` which would return  `Argument list too long` and it seems that I can only go for something like :

```
find dir1 -type f -name *.jpg -exec rm  {} \;
find dir2 -type f -name *.xml -exec rm  {} \;
```

I would like to know if there's a way to delete files in these two folders simultaneously?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have one harddrive? Why do you think running it simultaneously will be faster? And `-delete` is better then `-exec rm  {} \;`

Comment: You could try replacing `\;` with `+`, i.e. passing multiple, but not _too_ many, files at a time to `rm`.

Comment: @KamilCuk if you delte files in one folder and delete another one at the same time ,Wouldn't it be faster than delete all files in order?

Comment: If you have one drive, it can do one operation at a time, no matter what magic you do. When your operation is bound by I/O, optimization ends [rules of optimization #3](https://wiki.c2.com/?RulesOfOptimizationClub).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first optimization is replacing `-exec rm {} \;` by `-delete`. It will save from spawning one process per file, which is a lot... of processes.

The typical way is using `xargs -P`, and xargs also cares about too many arguments issue. Also note the quotes - `*.jpg` is expanded by the shell, while the intention is to pass it to `find`.

```
{ find dir1 -type f -name '*.jpg' -print0; find dir2 -type f -name '*.xml' -print0; } | xargs -0 -P$(nproc) rm
```

If  your operation was limited by the speed of I/O to your storage, the execution time decrease will be negligible anyway and could rather result in stalling your system by spawning too many processes, decreasing user experience. I think I would go with just `xargs -0 rm` without `-P`.

Comment: It turns out replacing -exec rm with -delete is way faster....Thanks,By the way...What does "-print0" mean? Thanks!